# Ansible set_fact value of No converted into False

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm having an annoying issue with `set_fact`, I set a var with value `No` but once I use the var in a template Ansible converts it to `False`. Is there a way around this YAML *Norway problem*? A single-quoted 'No' is converted to an unquoted False in the file.

Comment: Have a look at [booleans](https://yaml.org/type/bool.html) in YAML. `Yes`, `True`, `No`,  `False` are same. You may want to make it as text if you want a literal `"No"`.

Comment: I tried to add '''No''' result was 'No' while I need a clean No

Comment: When the value of `set_fact` is a boolean `No`, how does it matter if it changes to `False`? You may want to show some code (in the question) where you are trying to use the variable set with `set_fact`.

Comment: I'm using it with win_lineinfile and add it to a config file so False will break the config

Comment: @BugsBunny I don't know how you tried, but surrounding the value with quotes (single or double) gives the exact expected result:  https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/800629553ed221ec32d997bcbf9ffe4b

Comment: Strangely enough, when setting `"No"` with `set_fact`, it still gets converted to boolean when evaluated in Jinja context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use [multi line scalar](https://yaml-multiline.info/) YAML syntax to get around this and have the text `No` in the file contents.

Consider a simple text file `sample.txt` as below:

```
works? Yes
```

I am using an example with `lineinfile` (Linux), but should work similarly for Windows. A simple playbook with below tasks:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    var1: >
      No
- lineinfile:
    path: /tmp/sample.txt
    line: "works? {{ var1 }}"
    regexp: "^works"
```

When this playbook is run:

```
-works? Yes
+works? No
```

Comment: But this is the exact same as doing `'No'`

Comment: That's what I thought, but with `set_fact` it is working differently. If used in `vars:` section, it works as expected.

Comment: Using > No fixed the issue