# Jinja2 template if statement is not evaluating correctly

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a Jinja2 template that is sent as part of an email post patching of servers using Ansible. In it I have an if statement that is supposed to verify if a snapshot was taken. Here is the part of the playbook that sets the variable to evaluate:

```
- name: Was a snapshot taken
  set_fact:
    snapshot: "{{ 'yes' if (snap_result is changed and snap_result is not failed) else 'no'}}"
```

Here is the template:

```
**********************************************************
PATCH REPORT FOR {{ inventory_hostname }}
DATE: {{ ansible_date_time.date }}
TIME: {{ ansible_date_time.time }}
----------------------------------------------------------
{# Determine boot message #}
{% if booted == "yes" %}
  {% set boot_message = "The system rebooted!" %}
  {% set boot_message2 = "" %}
{% else %}
  {% set boot_message = "The system did NOT reboot!" %}
  {% set boot_message2 = "Either no reboot was required OR their was an issue." %}
{% endif %}

{# Determine Snapshot Message #}
{% if snapshot == "yes" %}
  {% set snapshot_message = "A snapshot was taken of your machine." %}
  {% set snapshot_message2 = "Contact DC Operations to delete the snapshot when you are satisfied all is well." %}
{% else %}
  {% set snapshot_message = "A snapshot was NOT taken of your machine." %}
  {% set snapshot_message2 = "None was requested or it failed." %}
{% endif %}

Vendor:                 {{ ansible_system_vendor }}
Server Type:            {{ ansible_product_name }}
BIOS Version:           {{ ansible_bios_version }}
O/S Distribution:       {{ ansible_distribution }}
Previous Dist rev:      {{ pre_patch_dist | to_nice_json }}
Upgraded Dist rev:      {{ ansible_distribution_version }}
Previous Kernel rev:    {{ pre_patch_kern|to_nice_json }}
Upgraded Kernel rev:    {{ ansible_kernel }}
Python Version:         {{ ansible_python_version }}
PrePatch Uptime:        {{ pre_uptime.stdout|to_nice_json }}
PostPatch Uptime:       {{ post_uptime.stdout|to_nice_json }}

{{ boot_message }}
{{ boot_message2 }}
{{ snapshot_message }}
{{ snapshot_message2 }}
{{ snapshot }}
System took {{ elapsed_boot_time }} seconds to reboot.
----------------------------------------------------------
******** END REPORT FOR {{ inventory_hostname }} *********
```

And here is the result:

```
**********************************************************
PATCH REPORT FOR na2-dvanstst06
DATE: 2021-04-07
TIME: 10:48:26
----------------------------------------------------------
    
    
Vendor:                 VMware, Inc.
Server Type:            VMware Virtual Platform
BIOS Version:           6.00
O/S Distribution:       Ubuntu
Previous Dist rev:      "18.04"
Upgraded Dist rev:      18.04
Previous Kernel rev:    "4.15.0-132-generic"
Upgraded Kernel rev:    4.15.0-132-generic
Python Version:         3.6.9
PrePatch Uptime:        " 10:48:20 up 5 days, 23:21,  1 user,  load average: 1.01, 1.00, 1.00"
PostPatch Uptime:       " 10:48:27 up 5 days, 23:22,  1 user,  load average: 1.01, 1.00, 1.00"

The system did NOT reboot!
Either no reboot was required OR their was an issue.
A snapshot was NOT taken of your machine.
None was requested or it failed.
Snapshot value is True
Booted value is False
System took 0 seconds to reboot.
----------------------------------------------------------
******** END REPORT FOR na2-dvanstst06 *********
```

As you can see at the end of the template I put in the value of `snapshot` and `booted` to see if they evaluated the same. Since the machine did not require a reboot `booted` evaluated correctly. However, even though `snapshot` was true it treated it as false. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are forcing the check for a string literal `"yes"` in the template. Whereas the `set_fact` sets `'yes'` as a boolean. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65507684/ansible-set-fact-value-of-no-converted-into-false/65511117#65511117).

So the `snapshot` variable is a boolean `True` rather than a string `'yes'` that you are expecting.

This is indicated by:

```
Snapshot value is True
```

So a simple change in your template for the `if` condition should do the trick:

```
{% if snapshot %}
  {% set snapshot_message = "A snapshot was taken of your machine." %}
  {% set snapshot_message2 = "Contact DC Operations to delete the snapshot when you are satisfied all is well." %}
{% else %}
  {% set snapshot_message = "A snapshot was NOT taken of your machine." %}
  {% set snapshot_message2 = "None was requested or it failed." %}
{% endif %}
```

Same applies for the `boot` variable. You can set it as a boolean `True/False` and use `if` condition accordingly.

Comment: I tried `{{% if snapshot %}}` and it still thinks that the condition is not met for the snapshot taken condition even though it clearly should have.

Comment: OK I have been at this too long. That did work. I just edited a duplicate j2 file that is in a different role so, of course, I was trying the same buggy code time and time again. Now I am going to figure out a common template directory for reusable templates.

Comment: I can understand, a kind of "numb-brain" syndrome. ;-) Glad it worked!